# Проблема с preg_match

Tags: preg_match, php

Всем привет!
В общем, простой код:

```
  $domain = 'сайт.рф';
  if(@preg_match("/^[0-9a-zа-я-.]+\.[0-9a-zа-я-]{2,6}$/u", $domain))
   {
    $enter = true;
   }
  else
   {
    $enter = false;
   } // возвращает true
```

---

```
  $domain = 'сайт.рф';
  if(@preg_match("/^[0-9a-zа-я-.]+\.[0-9a-zа-я-]{2,6}$/u", $domain) && @preg_match("/^[0-9a-zа-я]$/u", $domain[0]))
   {
    $enter = true;
   }
  else
   {
    $enter = false;
   } // возвращает false
```

Не понимаю, почему во втором варианте віходит false.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Unicode это двух(четырех)байтовая кодировка (в Вашем случае двух-), а обращение

```
$unicode[$x]
```

вернет один байт, который, естественно, не является буквой. Используйте функции для работы с Unicode или перепишите регулярное выражение на такое, которое заменит два условия одним выражением:

```
/^[0-9a-zа-я][0-9a-zа-я-.]*\.[0-9a-zа-я-]{2,6}$/u
```

или:

```
/^(?![-.])[0-9a-zа-я-.]+\.[0-9a-zа-я-]{2,6}$/u
```

Answer (score 0):

В первом условии у вас проверяется переменная $domain

```
preg_match("/^[0-9a-zа-я-.]+\.[0-9a-zа-я-]{2,6}$/u"
```

которая содержит до точки буквы, цифры, дефис и точку, а после точки от 2 до 6 цифр, букв или дефисов. Условие задано некорректно, дефис и точку надо отделять обратным слэшем,
т.е.

```
 preg_match("/^[0-9a-zа-я\-\.]+\.[0-9a-zа-я\-]{2,6}$/u"
```

Во втором случае вы пытаетесь проверить переменную как массив, что приводит к ошибке и выполняется условие иначе (else)

```
&& @preg_match("/^[0-9a-zа-я]$/u", $domain[0])
```

$domain[0] не является массивом. Уберите все @ в условии перед preg_match, не надо глушить вывод ошибок, вам же это и мешает при отладке.

Comment: @Ravel, в символьном классе можно не экранировать точку и дефис. Правда дефис должен быть либо в начали, либо в конце символьного класса тогда.  
Обращаться к строкам как к массиву можно, но только если строка Unicode, то это мало что даст, если не нужна именно работа с Unicode-байтами.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а вы уверены, что у него строка в Unicode? По поводу экранирования тут каждый решает сам, но спецсимволы рекомендуют экранировать, да и читается проще. Просто все вылезающие ошибки он закрыл @, вот и не видит проблемы.

Comment: Условие задано не корректно дефис и точку надо отделять обратный слэшем т.е.
preg_match("/^[0-9a-zа-я\-\.]+\.[0-9a-zа-я\-]{2,6}$/u"

А для чего нужно отделять обратным слэшем? Что оно дает?